# Share on facebook via link

Tags: facebook, share

I used this link to share on facebook:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://etgvtc.eu/%23/post/34&title=%2334%20Rekrutacja%20otwarta%20!&description=Po%20d%C5%82u%C5%BCszym%20czasie%20wsp%C3%B3lnych%20przemy%C5%9Ble%C5%84%20i%20rozwa%C5%BCa%C5%84%20odwa%C5%BCyli%C5%9Bmy%20si%C4%99%20powr%C3%B3ci%C4%87%20z%20nowymi%20si%C5%82ami%20i%20stu%20procentowym%20zaanga%C5%BCowaniem.&picture=http://panel.etgvtc.eu/api/image/cms/7947bdfb71c7f35dd45b0318dcb8060d.png
```

But some time ago it stopped working. Title, description and photo is not get from url. Some ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `og:url` set for your page is `<meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" />`. The Facebook crawler will try follow this URL to find the meta tags for the given page. Since this page does not exist, there is no title, description and photo to display.

You should update the `og:url` of your page to point to the correct URL and use the [Sharing Debugger Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) to force a re-rescrape of your page for the crawler to pick up the correct data.

Also, I can see that you are trying to set the title, description and picture explicitly. This will not work as this capability has now been [deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations). Instead these values will now be taken from the og tags of the given URL. You can read more about the basic og tags in [this doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters).

Comment: I cant use og:url because i use javascript to get post data.